# In C programming, why does square bracket get a higher precedence than prefix operator ++ in the statement: "a[i] = ++i;"?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I ran the following code through gcc based C compiler:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;                              // Line 1
    static int a[10];                       // Line 2
    
    a[i] = ++i;                             // Line 3
    
    printf("%d %d", a[0], a[1]);            // Line 4
    
    return 0;                               // Line 5
}
```

As per the precedence table provided in the textbook "The C Programming Language by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie" and the website: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence,  the precedence of square brackets (array subscript operator) is higher than that of prefix operator ++.

On running the program, the output i receive is: a[1] = 1.

I don't understand why the sequence of operations is not as follows:

1. a[0]
                             (put i = 0)
2. ++i                             (increment i by 1)
3. a[0] = 1
            
   (assign value of i to a[0])

and instead works as

1. ++i
                             (increment i by 1)
2. a[1]
                             (put i = 1)
3. a[1] = 1
            
   (assign value of i to a[1])

breaking the precedence rule. Please help me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)
Check "Example 2" in the top answer.

Comment: Precedence is not involved at all here.

Comment: `a[i] = ++i` is an unsequenced modification according to clang.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Thanks a lot! I was exactly looking for an explanation like that. The link pretty much explains about the undefined behavior of the language over such situations. Understood now.

Comment: @Akash Sen - While Gerhardh is right saying _Precedence is not involved at all here_, this is probably too laconic to enlighten you. Precedence matters if operators are "competing" for an operand. E. g. in `++a[i]`, the precedence rule causes this to be equivalent to `++(a[i])`, as you'd expect. In your `Line 3` there's no competition of operators, thus _Precedence is not involved_.

Comment: @Armali Thanks for clearing my idea about what precedence actually means. I pretty much can see what Gerhardh wished to point out.

Comment: The evaluations of `a[i]` and `++i` are *unsequenced* relative to each other - they can be evaluated in any order, even simultaneously (interleaved or in parallel).   With a few exceptions, C doesn't force left-to-right evaluation of expressions.  Similarly, the side effect of `++i` doesn't have to be applied immediately after evaluation.  Thus, the result can vary from compiler to compiler, even from run to run.  The language definition explicitly calls this out as *undefined behavior* - neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to produce a specific result or action.